# Custom User model error: AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'is_anonymous'

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-user

Trying to set up a custom user model that extends the base user. Some user will have login information and some will not, but I still want all users logged. That's what I think the error is saying.

In the default Django model they were logged, but now some users will just have just IP address and username. Other users will have more information like email, etc.

Gettin this error:

```
AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'is_anonymous'
```

Here is my custom user class:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(first_name, last_name, address1, state, zipcode, email, username, password):

        user=self.model(
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            address1 = address1,
            zipcode = zipcode,
            state = state,
            email=email, 
            username = username,
            password = password
            )
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.is_admin = False
        user.is_staff = False
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25
                )
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25
                )
    address1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=2, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 250)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    password = models.CharField(max_length =25,
        null=True)

    objects=MyUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'zipcode']

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} ({self.last_name}) ({self.email})'
```

How might I get this to work? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 11):

Your CustomUser class must inherit from AbstractBaseUser too. You didn't include it in your code. `models.Model` is not necessary then.
First you must do :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
```

And then

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
###
```

Comment: I would add here that models.Model is not necessary, it's enough to pass only AbstractBaseUser to CustomUser class

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this `property` in your `CustomUser` model:

```
@property
def is_anonymous(self):
    """
    Always return False. This is a way of comparing User objects to
    anonymous users.
    """
    return False
```